# How can I remove a universal css property from a image html tag coded in a WordPress project?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

A WordPress theme has been installed on my website. Once I click on a specified image, it will be directed to the right side of my window. That is because of my body direction style which has been set to RTL direction.

I tried different tricks such as adding `!important` to my image CSS class property, but it still leverages from `body *` universal style.

```
/* css */
body * {
 direction:rtl;
 }

 <!-- HTML -->
 <img class="tolb-img" src="">
```

How could I remove this universal style out of my `img` tag?
I want to set a `direction:ltr` to it and put it out of `body *` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override "all" * selector like this however the direction property specifies the text direction/writing direction within a block-level element so it should not change image position.

```
body *img.tolb-img {
   direction: ltr;
}
```